# Sql Server Transaction/Isolation Levels and Locking

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that updates 10 tables, and another one that updates only one of those 10 tables. Let’s call them sp_updateAll and sp_updateSingle respectively.
Say, the pseudo code for sp_updateAll is :

```
Create Stored Procedure sp_updateAll
Begin
    Begin TRAN
        UPDATE TABLE1 
        SET COLUMN = ‘VALUE’

        UPDATE TABLE2 
        SET COLUMN = ‘VALUE’
        …
        UPDATE TABLE6 
        SET COLUMN = ‘VALUE’
        …
        UPDATE TABLE10 
        SET COLUMN = ‘VALUE’
  COMMIT TRAN
End
```

The pseudo code for sp_UpdateSingle is this:
//this updates Table6 for e.g., in practice it could be any of the 10 table

```
Create Stored Procedure sp_updateSingle
Begin
    Begin TRAN
    IF sp_UpdateAll is in progress, return an error.
    UPDATE TABLE6 
    SET COLUMN = ‘VALUE’
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

I want to ensure that once sp_updateAll has begun executing, sp_updateSingle should return with an error. In other words, updates to individual tables should not be allowed while sp_UpdateAll is executing. 
Is there a way to achieve this using Isolation Levels/Locking Hints? Even if we set the Isolation Level to Serializable, there is a chance that sp_UpdateSingle executes together with sp_UpdateAll. For e.g. if both the transactions are run simultaneously, the following scenario could occur:

1. Tran1 begins executing sp_UpdateAll. Tran2 begins executing sp_UpdateSingle.
2. Tran1 gets switched before the UPDATE TABLE6 is reached. So TABLE6 is NOT LOCKED by Tran1.
3. Tran2 executes and commits.
4. Tran1 continues execution

Is this possible? If so, then what would be a good approach to avoid this case? Do we go for an additional table which maintains that Tran1 has begun executing (something like an InUse indicator)? Then this table should be the first table that gets updated in sp_UpdateAll; we set the indicator and clear it when sp_UpdateAll is complete. sp_UpdateSIngle checks for this indicator before executing the Update.
Kindly help with what approach would be good in such a scenario.

Thanks and Regards
Vikas

Comment: refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/8d6bf76a-af58-49ac-9414-d15bb4f48257

Answer (score 0):

I think transaction isolation level is not the answer here if I am understanding this correctly.

"I want to ensure that once sp_updateAll has begun executing, sp_updateSingle should return with an error. In other words, updates to individual tables should not be allowed while sp_UpdateAll is executing."

- I think you can create a global temp(dummy) table like ##sp1Executing at the start of the first transaction and drop this temp table when the transaction completes.
- In the second transaction, you can then check for if this table exists in a while loop , with possibly, a delay and run your transaction only if this table does not exist.